# Comet - HTTP Streaming with IHttpAsyncHandler - chunk not working

Tags: asp.net, http, comet, http-streaming, ihttpasynchandler

I'm trying to implement HTTP Streaming by using IHttpAsyncHandler and flushing.

Basically I'm flushing to the response every once and a while - saving the connection opened untill some timeout - and then the client should initiate another connection.

The flush indeed works and the client receives the flushes as they occur, however the response is getting aggregated. For example, if I send the following flushes:

```
"TextOnFlush1"
"TextOnFlush2"
"TextOnFlush3"
```

The client will get the following flushes (in the XMLHttpRequest.responseText):

```
"TextOnFlush1"
"TextOnFlush1""TextOnFlush2"
"TextOnFlush1""TextOnFlush2""TextOnFlush3"
```

As you can see eventually the client will have to handle with a very large message (which will contain all the previously flushes).
Is there a way to work with the flush, but to clean the respone on each flush?

Notice that the response header contains this header : "Transfer-Encoding:chunked", which means that I should indeed get the content in chunks but instead I get the aggregated messages.

Comment: You are flushing the entire response again to the stream every time.

Comment: Each time I'm writing other text to the response. The first time "TextOnFlush1" , the second "TextOnFlush2" , etc. But the client recieves the aggregated messages each time, any way to workaround this? or it isn't possible to clear the response in between flushes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is no way to get the browser to clean the response on each flush - so it is a good practice to limit this msg size and to refresh the streaming message on large data once in a while.